# Add count of group that does not exist for the row

Tags: count, arangodb, counting, aql

I have a collection of food orders, every object consist of day of the order and chosen food. My goal is to keep a record of the food during the week and count the numbers how many food of each type was ordered.

I've been using AQL for a while, but can not figure it out how add a counting, like add a number zero, for the days in which the specific food wasn´t ordered.

My AQL query is like this:

```
for fo in foodorders
 collect day = fo.dayOfTheWeek, chosenfood = fo.food with count into length
 return {dateOrder: day, food: chosenFood, cnt: length}
```

The result is like this:

```
[
  {
    "dayOfTheWeek": "Monday",
    "food": "Burger",
    "cnt": 400
  },
  {
    "date": "Monday",
    "food": "Salad",
    "cnt": 100
  },
  {
    "dayOfTheWeek": "Tuesday",
    "food": "Fries",
    "cnt": 200
  },
{
    "dayOfTheWeek": "Tuesday",
    "food": "Burger",
    "cnt": 200
  },
  {
    "dayOfTheWeek": "Tuesday",
    "food": "Salad",
    "cnt": 120
  },...
]
```

But I need something like this:

```
[
  {
    "dayOfTheWeek": "Monday",
    "food": "Burger",
    "cnt": 400
  },
  {
    "date": "Monday",
    "food": "Salad",
    "cnt": 100
  },
  {
    "date": "Monday",
    "food": "Fries",
    "cnt": 0
  },
  {
    "dayOfTheWeek": "Tuesday",
    "food": "Fries",
    "cnt": 200
  },
{
    "dayOfTheWeek": "Tuesday",
    "food": "Burger",
    "cnt": 200
  },
  {
    "dayOfTheWeek": "Tuesday",
    "food": "Salad",
    "cnt": 120
  },...
]
```

Comment: seems to me like you need to either 1) modify whatever program writes the food orders to the database to write an entry with 0 if there were no orders. 2) modify the program which reads your data to add the 0 orders if they find a day with a food with no entry (no AQL expert though, but why make AQL construct these 0 entries for you?)

Comment: I oversimplified the real life problem and missed the point of my query. I realized that the solution was before my eyes, what I needed was just change the data structure and flatten in. I will update my original post and maybe it will help somebody else.

Comment: perfect, please answer your own question then!